# Create virtual directory for .NET Core application in .NET Framework app

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core, virtual-directory, subapplication

I am trying to create a virtual directory (subfolder) in .net framework application. The directory is intended for .NET Core application. I need both of them to run under one domain. Currently I am using IIS Express and it is more suitable option for me than local IIS. I added the virtual directory to the .NET Framework application config.
An issue I've faced is that when main .NET Framework app is making http call to the .NET core one, I am getting an error that Report Viewer (which is used in .NET Framework app) cannot be loaded for .NET Core app. Of course I don't need the Report viewer in my .NET Core app. I need to load .NET Core app separately. Could you please advice ?

```
new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(`${settings.NotificationServiceConnectionUrl}/${notificationSettings.hubName}`, {
    accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken,
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .configureLogging(LogLevel.Error)
  .build()
```

Comment: "I need both of them to run under one domain." But you can achieve that by hosting ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core in separate sites and using a reverse proxy to merge the URLs. No need to mess up IIS Express configuration.

Comment: @LexLi ,Will it allow to send cookie from one app to another?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#share-authentication-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-apps

Comment: I read that article. At current state I need to put the apps under one domain

Comment: You don't need to put them under the same IIS site to achieve "under one domain". Think out of the box please and learn reverse proxy. And also use full IIS when you try to configure complex scenarios as IIS Express wasn't designed for such.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: @DingPeng, the problem still is not solved. I still facing that issue even under full IIS.

Comment: @LexLi, I have put main .net framework application under full iis. .net core app is still under iis express. Then I used url rewriting - it rewrites localhost:42185/Notification to localhost:5001. It is working fine for http request but for SignalR websocket's handshake it is not working for some reason, though it is also http request. This request is send to the main application. URL rewrite not working for it from some reason

Comment: How does a .NET Framework application call a .NET Core application? Can you provide part of the code?

Comment: @DingPeng, it is SignalR lib.I have added code

Comment: I think this should be your code problem, you may use Report Viewer in .NET Core, you need to check your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sub-application under the ASP.NET application, this sub-application is .NET Core application:

[image]

[image]

This is the code in the ASP.NET application, it will call the ASP.NET Core Web API application:

```
public ActionResult About()
        {
            

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/core/WeatherForecast");

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            ViewBag.Message = responseString;

            return View();
        }
```

[image]

We can also directly access ASP.NET Core Web API application:

[image]